# Python: function only works when created inside main code, not when imported with from functions import *

Tags: python, import, scope

I'm finding lots of variations on this question on Stackoverflow, but not quite the same:

I have something like the code below. If I define it within my main code it will find *df*, even when *df* itself is only defined after this function definition. It also works as expected: *df* is taken from the module scope and changed accordingly.

```
def update_df():
    df['x'] = df['y']
```

However, if I put it inside "functions.py" and use

```
from functions import *
```

it doesn't work anymore.

I would expect that the *import* * takes all definitions from *functions.py* and gives them the same definition in the main module. It doesn't fail on import, it does fail on usage.

How can I move this function into *functions.py* so it doesn't clutter my main code?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't let me paste the error code. Possibly some code injection check?
"Name Error: name 'df' is not defined"

Comment: Did you import DataFrame inside `functions.py`?

Answer (score 0):

The definiton of `update_df` in `functions.py` is using a *global* variable, and global here means global relative to `functions`. So `df` in the definition gets bound to the resp. value, in a *closure*.

Look for example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules) in the documentation (emphasise mine):

> A module can contain executable statements as well as function definitions. These statements are intended to initialize the module. **They are executed only the first time the module name is encountered in an import statement**. 1 (They are also run if the file is executed as a script.)
>
> **Each module has its own private namespace, which is used as the global namespace by all functions defined in the module. Thus, the author of a module can use global variables in the module without worrying about accidental clashes with a user’s global variables.** On the other hand, if you know what you are doing you can touch a module’s global variables with the same notation used to refer to its functions, `modname.itemname`.

You can verfiy that for exmaple by using [`getclosurevars`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?#inspect.getclosurevars) from the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?#module-inspect) module, which extracts the closures for a function. If you put the following into the `functions.py` file

```py
import pandas as pd

def update_df():
    df['x'] = df['y']

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b'], 'y': [1, 2]})
```

and then do

```py
from inspect import getclosurevars
from functions import *

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['A', 'B'], 'y': [10, 20]})
print(f'Before function call: {getclosurevars(update_df).globals = }')
update_df()
print(f'After function call: {getclosurevars(update_df).globals = }')
```

in `main.py` (your file is most likely named otherwise) then you'll get

```
Before function call: getclosurevars(update_df).globals = {'df':    x  y
0  a  1
1  b  2}
After function call: getclosurevars(update_df).globals = {'df':    x  y
0  1  1
1  2  2}
```

Now, as mentioned at the end of the quoted documentation, you could `import functions` and then manipulate the `functions.df` by something like `functions.df = df`, then use `update_df` and retrieve the updated dataframe back by `df = functions.df`. But that's rather awkward and I wouldn't recommend it. I'd rather, as proposed in the now deleted answer, change the definition and then give the `df` to `update_df` as an argument. Alternatively, you could define a class in `functions.py` that takes a dataframe, puts it in an attribute, and then uses a `.update_df` method on it. But I don't know if that's sensible in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a function is created, Python gives that function a reference to the module namespace in which the function is being defined, which is considered as its global namespace. It's stored in `__globals__` attribtue.

file1.py:

```py
def fn():
    pass

print(hex(id(globals())))
```

file2.py:

```py
from file1 import fn

print(hex(id(globals())))
print(hex(id(fn.__globals__)))
```

Here is the output of running file2.py:

```
0x7ff766184700  ##
0x7ff76613e3c0
0x7ff766184700  ##
```

Then inside the function, whenever you ask for a variable which is not in its local namespace, it will search through this namespace(and then the built-in namespace of course).